# TS/playwright - how to post api request with x-www-form-urlencoded body?

Tags: javascript, typescript, playwright, playwright-test, x-www-form-urlencoded

I need to create playwright API request with x-www-form-urlencoded body:
Example from postman:
[working postman request example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dB9Z8.png)

I was trying to it that way:

```js
  async getNewApiAccesToken({request})
    {
        const postResponse = await request.post("https://login.microsoftonline.com//token",{
            ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
            FormData: {
                'client_id': 'xyz',
                'client_secret': 'xyz',
                'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
                'scope': 'api://xyz'
            }
        })
        console.log(await postResponse.json());
        return postResponse;
```

But it is not working :/ Could you tell me how can i compose this kind of request in playwright?

Answer (score 8):

Ok, i found a solution!

```js
 async getNewApiAccesToken({request})
    {
        const formData = new URLSearchParams();
        formData.append('grant_type', 'client_credentials');
        formData.append('client_secret', '8xyz');
        formData.append('client_id', 'xyz');
        formData.append('scope', 'api://xyz/.default');
        const postResponse = await request.post("https://login.microsoftonline.com/9xyz/v2.0/token",{
            ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
            headers:{
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
              },    
            data: formData.toString()  
        })
        return postResponse;
        
    };
```

Comment: any help on this to convert into java?

Comment: This doesn't work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this:

```
await request.post('https://login.microsoftonline.com/9xyz/v2.0/token', {
  headers:{
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  },  
  form: {
    grant_type: 'client_credentials',
    client_secret: '8xyz',
    client_id: 'xyz',
    scope: 'api://xyz/.default'
  }
});
```

According to the documentation:

"To send form data to the server use form option. Its value will be encoded into the request body with application/x-www-form-urlencoded encoding"

https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-apirequestcontext#api-request-context-post